# Why didn't saving the mongoose work in this situation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have 2 cycles. The first one is for sorting posts. And the second one is to sort through the comments under these posts.

```
            Post.find().then(post =>{
              for(let i=0; i<post.length; i++){
                for(let ic=0; ic<post[i].comments.length; ic++){
                  if(post[i].comments[ic].user.secret_id == req.session.secret_id){
                    post[i].comments[ic].user.user_id = req.body.id;
                  }
                }
              }

              post.save()
               
            })
```

It's doesn't work

TypeError: post.save is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It's because mongoose returns something called "mongoose object or mongo object" with additional metadata, not a plain javascript object when querying to database. So when you're performing "post[i].comments..." on the 5th line, it's modifying the mongoose object, you're trying to set a property which is calculated via for loop, but post isn't an array. There are this kind of typos, correct them and let's see what are the results.